# How to setAlpha to android Button

Tags: android

I have three buttons, sharing same background image, i want to disable button one of them by using Alpha.

But when i am using the following code:

```
 button1.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

it is changing the background for all three buttons. but i need for only one.
can we done by using by Alpha()?? or some other things we can use so that button will looks in disabled mode.

Comment: Just to check,are you sure that each button has a different ID?

Comment: Hi Lumis, thanks for response, i have checked, each button have its unique id.

Comment: Find it very interesting that one can alter the background for all buttons in this way, thanks for posting this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set alpha using `AlphaAnimation` to any view

**Sample Code**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);  
float alpha = 0.45f;
AlphaAnimation alphaUp = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
alphaUp.setFillAfter(true);
btn.startAnimation(alphaUp);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the user has disabled animations on the device.

Answer (score 8):

```
nextBtn.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

or

```
nextBtn.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Comment: Note, nextBtn.setAlpha(0.5f);  setAlpha(int) has been around since API level 1, but is deprecated since level 16. setAlpha(float) continues to work. Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831775/difference-between-setalpha-and-setimagealpha

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn);  
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagen);  
    d.setAlpha(60);  
    btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);  
}
```

Comment: `d.setAlpha(60);` requires API level 11+

Answer (score 1):

In my case I set one button to alpha 75. But all the other buttons with same background color also changed to alpha 75. Calling `mutate()` solved the problem.

Pavel Dudka' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27116347/7311767) works perfectly for my case.

```
buttonArrivals.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(180);
buttonDepartures.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(255);
```